# attach media stream Not allowed to load local resource: blob:blobinternal:///

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, webrtc

I am using https://github.com/BasqueVoIPMafia/cordova-plugin-iosrtc and I am having a hard time to allow ios 11 to work with internal blobs.

Do you have any idea how to configure cordova 7 (ios engine 4.5+) in order to make this works?
this is my code for ataching stream

```
attachMediaStream = function (element, stream) {
    element.srcObject = stream;
}
```

Thank you!